# Ajax doesn't fire onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know the URL is working as intended as i logged that to the console and it is fine. However I can't get "Good News" to log to the console when readyState == 4 and status == 200. I tried removing readState and it still wouldn't log. I tried logging the status and It would only fire once with a value of 0. This is the first time I am working with Ajax so any help is appreciated.

```
function setupRequest(){
  var bttn = document.querySelector('#send');

  bttn.addEventListener('click', sendData)
}

setupRequest();

function sendData () {

console.log('ran')
  var url = 'localhost/bev/drinks.php';

  var data = document.getElementById('input').value;
  url += '?' + 'alcohol=' + data;

console.log(url)

 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log('good news')
            console.log(this.responseText)
        } else {
    console.log(this.status)
        }
    }

 request.open('GET', url, true);
 request.send;

  console.log('sent')

}
```

Comment: have you tried entering in the protocol for the URL into your code so use "http://" localhost and not localhost? (the comments was auto creating a link so ignore the quotes)

Comment: Also look in the console and network console to see you are getting what you expect. You cannot do this from harddisk. The page has to be served from a web server and the drinks from the same server or a server that supports CORS

Comment: You need to actually call `request.send` using `request.send()`.  You aren't doing anything unless you add parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually call `send()`.  You aren't doing anything whenever you say `request.send;`

```js
function setupRequest() {
  var bttn = document.querySelector('#send');

  bttn.addEventListener('click', sendData)
}

setupRequest();

function sendData() {

  console.log('ran')
  var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  var data = document.getElementById('input').value;
  //url += '?' + 'alcohol=' + data;

  console.log(url)

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log('good news')
      console.log(this.responseText)
    } else {
      console.log(this.status)
    }
  }

  request.open('GET', url, true);

  // You wrote (without parentheses):
  ///////////////////
  // request.send; //
  ///////////////////

  // You need to write
  request.send();

  console.log('sent')

}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="send">Btn</button>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: That was the problem! I am a php developer so sorry for my beginner mistake. I was following an online tutorial and they had wrote it the same way as me so I was confused.

Comment: So this should be closed and deleted as a typo-type question